# Conditional Logisitc regression analysis with mgcv gam models

Tags: r, plot, gam, cox-regression, mgcv

I am running a GAM model through the mgcv package with `family = cox.ph()` and have my data grouped by strata (`strata = id`). The data corresponds to one use location for an individual animal and 20 random locations associated with that individual that were available for use.

```
require(mgcv)
require(survival)
require(smoothHR)

gam1 = gam(time1~s(DWL)+strata(id),family=cox.ph(),method = "REML",data=dataset, weight = event1)
```

The model is running smoothly but I am unsure how to plot relationships to x-variable. `DWL` is a continuous variable. I have used the following to graph predictions:

```
x = seq(0,120) #extent of DWL values
plot(gam1,residuals=T,trans=function(x)exp(x)/(1+exp(x)),shade=T)
```

I am a bit confused about the use of the `trans` argument in the plot syntax. Using the `cox.ph()` for your family agrument, Is the `logit-link` the proper way to evaluate your predicted y-response to the x variable `DWL`?

Thank you,

P Farrell